# How do I make a drop down menu appear over the top of another div?

Tags: html, css

This has been bugging me for two days now
I have read numerous websites and explanations and seemingly tried everything, but clearly I have missed something.

Below is code taken almost as is from the W3schools website and I have inserted it into a very basic page, but the dropdown menu wants to remain within its own div and not open on top of the one below it.

I have tweaked the css to include various z-index values, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone help me please?

Here is the page and the css file in their entireties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="fullpage">

 <div class="pageheader">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="pagemenu">
  <div class="mainmenu">

   <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
   </div>

  </div> 
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.fullpage {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #800000;
 z-index: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.pageheader {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 160px;
 background-color: #b00000;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
 min-width: 900px;
 height: 160px;
 background-color: #b0b0b0;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.pagemenu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 160px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 56px;
 background-color: #202020;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.mainmenu {
 margin: auto;
 width: 1200px;
 height: 56px;
 background-color: #000000;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="fullpage">

 <div class="pageheader">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="pagemenu">
  <div class="mainmenu">

   <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
   </div>

  </div> 
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove 'overflow: hidden" from here:

```
.pagemenu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 160px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 56px;
 background-color: #202020;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove overflow hidden from pagemenu,mainmenu and navbar. u cant see the drop down because overflow hidden is hidding the dropdown

```css
.fullpage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #800000;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
   }
   
   .pageheader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #b00000;
   }
   
   .header {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 900px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
   }
   
   .pagemenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #202020;
   }
   
   .mainmenu {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #000000;
   }
   
   body {
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   .navbar {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #333;
   }
   
   .navbar a {
     float: left;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   
   .dropdown {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 4;
   }
   
   .dropdown .dropbtn {
     font-size: 16px;  
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     background-color: inherit;
     font-family: inherit;
     margin: 0;
   }
   
   .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     background-color: red;
   }
   
   .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   }
   
   .dropdown-content a {
     float: none;
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
   
   .dropdown-content a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
   }
   
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 100;
   }
```